# Fuel SDK : Retriving Click Activity (Links and click rates)

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I would like to create a console c# application to retrieve the Tracking Click activity to our local database. I checked the FuelSDK link : https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/tracking/click-tracking.html
.Where i see i can get URL and URLID and i suppose i get as in picture attached (img1.jpg) only id and links. But i would need to have click rates and link url of all the links in a particular email sends (e.g. img2.jpg and img3.jpg). We can find that info in the exacttarget site (img2.jpg and img3.jpg) though.

Briefly: i would like to get click activity tracking info Total,Unique,NetCTRs
 as in image 3(img2.jpg) or as in image3 (img3.jpg)

Image1:

[image: Image1]

Image2:

[image: Image2]

Image3:

[image: Image3]

Is it doable? Some one has done similar or any experience?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you are looking for is: LinkSend

You can filter this object by the SendID property (same thing as Job ID) to receive a list of all of the links for a send with a count of total clicks and unique clients.

Complete list of retrievable properties:

```
•ID
•SendID
•PartnerKey
•Client.ID
•Client.PartnerClientKey
•Link.ID
•Link.PartnerKey
•Link.TotalClicks
•Link.UniqueClicks
•Link.URL
•Link.Alias
```

The C# SDK does not have support for this object, but it can be accessed by going directly against SOAP.

edit: I updated the SDK to add LinkSend, example at: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/Dot9/objsamples/Sample_LinkSend.cs

Comment: Thank you.  I  suppose this is it. I will work on this next week for my project.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I don't believe you can retrieve the aggregate click activity via API.</strike> (Updated per [Mac's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5080/mac) [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/112088/5202))

What we've done in the past is to create a set of [Query Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) that aggregate this data in a Data Extension.  Once that's done, you can [retrieve the data](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extension-rows/data-extension-row-retrieve.html) via API.

You can retrieve some aggregate data from the [Send](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/send/) object, but it's not click-level detail.